# Mocking a DirectLine api call in a jasmine test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm currently using the WebChat.js javascript library in my angular 7 web app to render a webchat interface. I'm trying to do some jasmine testing on the component and having some issues mocking some of the functions in the library.

Here's the code for my component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

/**
* Declares the WebChat property on the window object.
*/
declare global {
    interface Window {
        WebChat: any;
    }
}

window.WebChat = window.WebChat || {};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-web-chat',
    templateUrl: './web-chat.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./web-chat.component.css']
})
export class WebChatComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("botWindow") botWindowElement: ElementRef;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const directLine = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            secret: "mysecretkey",
            webSocket: false
        });

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
                directLine: directLine,
                userID: "Agent"
            },
            this.botWindowElement.nativeElement
        );

        directLine
            .postActivity({
                from: { id: "Agent", name: "Agent" },
                text: "command watch",
                type: "message",
                value: "token"
            })
            .subscribe(
                id => console.log(`Posted activity, assigned ID ${id}`),
                error => console.log(`Error posting activity ${error}`)
            );

    }
}
```

And here's what I've got so far in my spec.ts file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { WebChatComponent } from './web-chat.component';

fdescribe('WebChatComponent', () => {
    let component: WebChatComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<WebChatComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('window.WebChat', ['renderWebChat', 'createDirectLine']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [WebChatComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: window.WebChat, useValue: spy }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WebChatComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Basically, I'm working through it in steps, and currently I'm stuck at an error saying that the `TypeError: window.WebChat.createDirectLine is not a function` but I thought that creating a spy and providing it in the beforeEach section would deal with that.

Am I going about this the right way? I'm honestly not too sure how to effectively mock the calls the DirectLine API makes in my WebChatComponent

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Web Chat writes so much to the global `window` and this isn't happening for the test. All you have to do is make sure the Web Chat script (in your `index.html` file) loads for the test.

To do so, in `karma.conf.js`, add:

```
files: [
    'https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js',
],
```

You may be using a different webchat.js, like `/master/webchat.js`. Just use the same one you have in `index.html`.

Result:

[image]